# Setting default cursor on a text field in a panel in java swing

Tags: java, swing, textfield

I am making a application in Java that uses a JTextField. Now, I want, as soon as I run the app, the cursor to be put automatically in that so that the user doesn't have to click on it and then write the text. I have tried requestFocusInWindow() but it doesn't work.The focus goes to the Panel present in the Jframe first but I have to click on the text field to edit it. Can anyone help me solve this,really appreciate it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: There's no real way to know when a component is actually displayed on the screen.  You might use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or provide some kind of method that allows callers to tell you when they've added your component to a window (and made it visible)

Answer (score 0):

Check what `requestFocusInWindow()` is returning. It returns true if it is likely to succeed, and false if it definitely fails.

Also, try waiting until `JTextField`'s parents are visible when you call `requestFocusInWindow()`. In my experience, calling the method before parents are visible usually doesn't work.

Here's a paragraph from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html):

> If you want to ensure that a particular component gains the focus the
>   first time a window is activated, you can call the
>   requestFocusInWindow method on the component after the component has
>   been realized, but before the frame is displayed.

And then provides this code sample:

```
frame.pack(); // Realize the components.
button.requestFocusInWindow(); 
frame.setVisible(true); // Display the window.
```

I suspect that when the components are "realized" (whatever that means), Java automatically delegates the focus. I also suspect that if you do not call `pack()`, the components are not "realized" until you call `setVisible(true)`